Error setting properties on a gremlin vertex with UUIDs
I'm trying to setup a local gremlin server to use UUIDs (to mimic neptune), but I'm getting an error when I try to set any property on a vertex:
It happily creates a vertex with a UUID:
gremlin> g.addV('X')
==>v[1c29844f-1b3e-4fa5-b107-b23bc15db0d2]

But if I try to set any property it fails:
gremlin> g.V('1c29844f-1b3e-4fa5-b107-b23bc15db0d2').property('a', 'b')
Expected an id that is convertible to class java.util.UUID but received class java.lang.Long - [0]

I get the same behaviour if I try to set it immediately, e.g. with g.addV('X').property('a', 'b')
For reference, my graph config is as follows:
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerTransactionGraph
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=UUID
gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager=UUID

Edit
It seems that if I change it from TinkerTransactionGraph to TinkerGraph it works fine. Is there some extra configuration needed for TinkerTransactionGraph to understand UUIDs?
